# PLS discriminant analysis - explained variance

Tags: statistics

I have a problem understanding a main thing about the PLS discriminant analysis. In my program there is an output, where the amount of variance explained by each factor for both the independent and the dependent variables is printed out seperately (e.g. factor 1 explains 70% for the indep. vars and 30% for the dependent vars, whereas factor 2 explains 20% for indep.vars and 60% for dependent vars). However I don't understand why I need the explained amount of variance for the independent variables. Can anybody explain this to me in an easy way?

Thank you!